# Django retrieve time when the post was liked

Tags: python, django

I need to make a report showing analytics(time and user) of post likes and un-likes.

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="post_like")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

views.py

```
...
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get("post_id"))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("posts:single", args=[str(post.user), str(pk)]))
...
```

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Your database is only saving **who is liking it**, but doesn't retain information of **when it happened**. Your `created_at` despite the name, is getting updated whenever the model gets saved, so it will only tell you when it was last liked/unliked/changed.

What you need to do is add additional model/table that will also log all the changes to the likes, so that you can create this report from it.

Comment: could you please give me a hint how to log such change?

Comment: I think the answer by Kenneth outlines a good approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your dont have a field foR what you want.My advice would be create another table for Likes like this.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    LIKE=1
    DISLIKE=-1
    VALUE_CHOICES=(
        ('LIKE','LIKE'),
        ('DISLIKE','DISLIKE')
        )
    value=models.IntegerField(choices=VALUE_CHOICES)
    user=models.ForeignKey(
        to="user",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    post=models.ForeignKey(
        to="Post",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE

        )
    time_stamp=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```